# C++ multiple inheritance assign base class to derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I want to assign base classes to derived class alternatively, since both base classes share same function/attribute names. This is the situation:

```
class Base1 {
    public:
        int num = 3;
};

class Base2 {
    public:
        int num = 4;
};

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2{
    
};
```

I'd like to implement code in such a way:

```
Derived d;
d = become(Base1);      // I need this "function"
cout << d.num;  // 3
d = become(Base2);      // I need this "function"
cout << d.num;  // 4
```

How can I solve it?
Thank you

Comment: This would be quite awful to implement. However, you can directly do `Base1 &asBase1 = d; asBase1.num; // 3`.

Comment: This may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You would like to implement code in such a way, but how did you decide that multiple inheritance is the first step to achieving that?

Comment: Or are you looking for `d.Base1::num`?

Comment: Sorry, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: If I'm reading this question correctly, you actually want `std::variant`.

Comment: *I need this "function"* Write it? *cout << d.num;* This you can't have, `d.num` is ambiguous. You probably need something other than inheritance here.